# Show that there exist $g\in C^{\infty}$ such that $f(x)=g(x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, even,.
>
> Show that there exist $g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^+},\mathbb{R})$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}, f(x)=g(x^2)$

My attempt :

Let $g$ the function defined on $\mathbb{R^+}$ by $g(x)=f(\sqrt{x})$, it's clear that $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^+}$ and $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb{R^+_*}$.

So the problem is to find the limit at $0$ but I don't know how can I proceed.

EDIT: Here $\mathbb{R^+}=[0,+\infty)$

Comment: The issue is to prove (right-) smoothness of $g$ at $0$.

Comment: There are detailed answers on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72497). This is orginally a theorem of Whitney.

Comment: @user10676: Whitney's theorem is far, far more general and challenging!

Comment: @TedShifrin. I don't have the paper of Whitney, but according to [Glaeser](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SL/SL_1962-1963__5_/SL_1962-1963__5__A2_0/SL_1962-1963__5__A2_0.pdf) (cf exemple 1), Whitney proved that $\{g(x^2) : g \in C^\infty(R)\}$ is exactly the set of even differentiable functions. This is what the OP is asking for accept that $g$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$ (I am not talking about Whitney extension theorem).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was of course thinking of the Whitney Extension Theorem. In the MO post, one person comments that it follows immediately from Taylor's Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Because $f$ is even, the Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $0$ is also even. If $P_{2n,f}(x)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^n a_{2j}x^{2j}$, prove that $P_{n,g}(x)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^n a_{2j}x^j$. Now deduce smoothness of $g$ at $0$ (from the right).

Comment: Thanks, but you mean taylor young : $f(x) =\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k + R_n(x)$ ? In my course this relation is true only when $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $I$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ so I am a bit lost..

Comment: Take any interval $I$ containing the origin in its interior. :)

Comment: Thanks (+1), I will work on your hint.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that a smooth even function looks like a parabola sufficiently close to zero, so that its composition with $\sqrt x$ is still smooth near zero.

To make this precise, you want to remember that the derivative is the best linear approximation: that is, for any differentiable function whatsoever we get $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+h(x)x^2$, where $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x)$ is finite. But for $f$ even, $f'(0)=0$, because $$0=f(x)-f(-x)=2f'(0)x+h(x)x^2-h(-x)x^2$$ And for small enough $x$ we can suppose $|h(x)x^2-h(-x)x^2|\leq (|h(x)|+|h(-x)|)x^2< 2f'(0)x$-to see this, divide by $x^2$ on both sides and use that $h$ converges at $0$.

Thus $f(x)=f(0)+h(x)x^2$ and the first derivative of $f(\sqrt x)=f(0)+h(\sqrt x)x$ exists: namely, it's $h(0)$.

Comment: I see you've started to follow what I suggested in my hint. But you're not done. We want smoothness.

Comment: Ah, right, I see the difference with your suggestion now. I guess another way to proceed is to point out $h$ itself is smooth and even and induct.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are going to argue $h$ is smooth, directly.